# Changing text in a textbox when using as a toggle item

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a report with 2 pie charts, one giving data in hours, one as a percentage.

I have a textbox that when clicked switches the visibility of both the charts.

Can I change the text when this is clicked?

So when report renders for example text box text is 'View as %', and then when clicked changes to 'View in Hours'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this directly, you cannot change the content once the report is rendered using the standard web portal/manager that is provided with SSRS.

The closest you could get would be to have two labels next to the textbox you have that does the switching, each of them in the exact same location so they overlap. One initially set to visible the other to hidden but both switch based on your existing textbox. Something like

[image]

Comment: However, after deployment, overlapped textboxes are being thrown about in firefox, chrome, and IE.... annoying!

Comment: Hmm... I know overlapping items are not supported by some renderers but I've done similar things in the past without issues as long as I was only using a browser. I'll see if I can do some testing later.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by putting the two text boxes adjacent to each other. `Switch To:` `%` `Hours`. I was expecting a gap to appear between `Switch To:` and `Hours` when toggling, but this isnt the case and the text boxes render perfectly.